# Ansible shell module behaves differently than the Linux shell

Tags: shell, ansible, formatting, command, output

I wish to grab the output of Linux's multiple commands in a Single Line like shown below. As you can see the output of `ls` and `cksum` are printed in one line.

```
# myvar=`ls -ltr test.yml; cksum<test.yml | tr '\n' '\t'`
# echo $myvar
```

> Output:
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 298 May 3 04:46 test.yml 3415682946 298

Now, i wish to do the same in Ansible so below is the ansible command:

```
# ansible localhost -m shell -a "ls -ltr test.yml; cksum<test.yml | tr '\n' '\t'"
```

However, as you can see the output of cksum is printed on the second line instead of one.

> Output:
>   localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 298 May  3 04:46 test.yml
>
> 3415682946 298

Using the command module throws error.

Can you please help me understand how can I tweak the ansible command to get the output in a single line for both `ls` and `cksum` ?

Note: you can quickly test this as well on your systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are translating newline->tab for the wrong command, and the `echo` is actually skewing your test results. The command you want is:

```
ansible localhost -m shell -a "ls -ltr test.yml | tr '\n' '\t'; cksum<test.yml"
```

If you ran `ls -ltr test.yml; cksum<test.yml | tr '\n' '\t'` without assigning it to a variable you will see the output split across two lines. The `echo` is actually stripping the additional white space. To echo your true result (with white space included), enclose the variable in double quotes:

```
echo "$myvar"
```